# HTML output of Google Assistant SDK is truncated

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying out the android things example app and have set the Screen Output to use HTML.

The output seems to be truncated and not terminated by the **end html tag**. Here is the actual output. Do you have any suggestions?

I'm using the grpc project/library from the android things example using the com.google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2

```
# com.google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2.AssistResponse@e3565447
    screen_out {
      data: "<html> <head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"> <link href=\"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700\" rel=\"stylesheet\"></head> <style>html,body{background:transparent;margin:0}#popout{bottom:0;box-sizing:border-box;font-family:\"Roboto\",sans-serif;font-size:40px;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;font-smoothing:antialiased;position:absolute;transform:translateZ(0);transition:opacity 500ms;transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;overflow:hidden;width:100%}#popout div{font-family:\'Roboto\',arial,sans-serif}.popout-shadow{background-image:linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 100%);height:5.4em;width:100%}.popout-overflow-shadow-down{background-image:linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 100%);bottom:144px;display:none;position:absolute;height:48px;width:100%;z-index:100}.popout-overflow-shadow-up{background-image:linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(25,25,25,0.97) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,0.0) 100%);display:none;top:5.4em;height:48px;position:absolute;width:100%;z-index:100}.popout-content{background-color:rgba(25,25,25,.97);padding-right:28px;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:hidden}.popout-content:hover,.popout-content:focus{outline:none}.popout-asbar:hover,.popout-asbar:focus{outline:none}.inactive{opacity:.4}#carousel-container{left:0;overflow-x:initial;transition:300ms ease-in-out;transform:translateZ(0)}</style> <script>\nwindow.Assistant = window.Assistant || {};var Assistant = window.Assistant;if (Assistant.clear)Assistant.clear();\nAssistant.clear = function(){if (Assistant.cleanup){Assistant.cleanup();}\nwindow.Assistant = {};};</script> <script>\nwindow.Assistant = window.Assistant || {};var Assistant = window.Assistant;\nAssistant.displayTimeoutMs = 20000;\nAssistant.micTimeoutMs = 0;\nAssistant.hideTimerId = undefined;\nAssistant.micTimerId = undefined;\nAssistant.isUsingRelativeIndex = false;\nAssistant.SUGGESTION_PROMPT_ID = \'suggestion_prompt\';\nAssistant.SUGGESTION_PROMPT;\nAssistant.SUGGESTION_CLASS_NAME = \'suggestion\';\nAssistant.POPOUT;\nAssistant.ICON;\nAssistant.cleanup = function(){Assistant.cleanupTimer_();};\nAssistant.updateDisplayTimeoutMs = function(displayTimeoutMs){if (displayTimeoutMs >= 0){Assistant.displayTimeoutMs = displayTimeoutMs;}\n};\nAssistant.updateMicTimeoutMs = function(micTimeoutMs){if (micTimeoutMs >= 0){Assistant.micTimeoutMs = micTimeoutMs;}\n};\nAssistant.updateIsUsingRelativeIndex = function(usingRelativeIndex){Assistant.isUsingRelativeIndex = !!usingRelativeIndex;};\nAssistant.cleanupTimer_ = function(){if (Assistant.hideTimerId){window.clearTimeout(Assistant.hideTimerId);Assistant.hideTimerId = undefined;}\nif (Assistant.micTimerId){window.clearTimeout(Assistant.micTimerId);Assistant.micTimerId = undefined;}\n};\nAssistant.getSuggestionPrompt = function(){if (!Assistant.SUGGESTION_PROMPT){Assistant.SUGGESTION_PROMPT =\ndocument.getElementById(Assistant.SUGGESTION_PROMPT_ID);}\nreturn Assistant.SUGGESTION_PROMPT;};\nAssistant.run = function(){Assistant.POPOUT = document.getElementById(\'popout\');Assistant.ICON = document.getElementsByClassName(\'assistant-icon\')[0];Assistant.keepShowing();};\nAssistant.keepShowing = function(){if (!Assistant.POPOUT){return;}\nAssistant.cleanupTimer_();Assistant.slideUpPopout();if (Assistant.displayTimeoutMs){Assistant.hideTimerId = setTimeout(function(){Assistant.hideTimerId = undefined;Assistant.slideDownPopout();if (typeof Assistant.maybePopulateNotification !== \'undefined\'){Assistant.maybePopulateNotification();}\n},Assistant.displayTimeoutMs);}\nif (Assistant.micTimeoutMs){Assistant.micStartListen();Assistant.micTimerId = setTimeout(function(){Assistant.micTimerId = undefined;Assistant.micStopListen();},Assistant.micTimeoutMs);}\n};\nAssistant.toggleElement = function(ele,display){var target = display ?\'\' :\'none\';if (ele.style.display != target){ele.style.display = target;}\n};\nAssistant.updateSuggest
2020-05-22 16:43:43.879 24567-24990/com.densoft.android I/EmbeddedAssistant: Assistant response:
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was Logcat in Android. I found that it is truncating the log message if size is over 4K.